# Looking to ground roof mounted mast - No ground rod at service entrance

Tags: grounding, tv-antenna

So I'm looking to install an anemometer on my roof.

With my last house, in Ohio built in 2000, when I added a TV antenna there was a grounding rod near the electric meter.

However, my current house, in Utah built in 1979, there isn't a ground rod near the meter.  It appears cable guy simply "grounded" to the incoming metal service conduit.
[image]

FYI: I believe the loose green wire goes up to where a DISH antenna used to be.

The house (actually the whole neighborhood) has underground electric service.  Though the house in Ohio did also.

One other thing I noticed, there's no ground jumper around shutoff valve & pressure regulator for the water service in this house like there was on the Ohio house.

So the question, is my house properly grounded?  Is the service conduit functioning as ground?

Assuming the answers to both those are yes, then I just need to ground my new roof mounted mast to the incoming service conduit right?

Comment: Who's your electric utility?

Comment: @threephaseel Rocky Mountain power

Comment: Is there a wire bonding the water system to the electrical system somewhere?  Is your plumbing plastic or metal, for that matter?

Comment: I don't know... Not that I can see... But 3/4 of the basement is finished...

Comment: Metal plumbing ... Again as far as I can see...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's likely that merely doing what the cable guy did meets "legal code" for that county.
I prefer to treat antennas like lightning rods since that's exactly what they become during a lightning strike.
So I drive in a 8 foot dedicated ground rod and run a minimum of #10 solid copper or #8 solid aluminum wire to the antenna mast.
Then run a #6 copper bonding jumper from the rod to the main electrical ground to meet code.